# set part of the text in text view android

Tags: android, styles, textview

I have a text view and I want to control the style of the text. My Problem is that I want to change the style of only a fraction of the text. for example when a user do something the first three letters of the text becomes red. I know how to do it for the entire text. But no idea about applying the style to only part of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ForegroundColorSpan`

Try like this

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Your Text");
        // make "Your" (characters 0 to 4) Red
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);
        // make "Text" (characters 4 to 8) Blue
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 4, 8, 0);
        // save our styled text into the Button
        textview.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

For FontStyle use StyleSpan for reference [StyleSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html)

**So use can use custom typeface with the help of StyleSpan.**

```
textview.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), start,
                    end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Hope this will help you.